# Search for a string in lots files in a directory, if found, save the file name and line

Tags: text-processing, files, string, search, file-search

I have several files, with different names. no specific format for them. But all are `.txt`. For example:

```
example.txt
flower.txt
abc.com.txt
```

They are in the same directory. I want to search for a string line in all the files, e.g. `<html>`. Then, if found, I want to extract the line where the string found. Then I want to save the search results in a results.txt file as follows:

file name,line

For example, if the string `<html>` was found in `example.txt` and `abc.com.txt`, then the results file will be:

```
example.txt,<html>[the rest of the line where html is found]
abc.com.txt,<html>[the rest of the line where html is found]
```

How can I achieve this in linux?

Comment: How about `filename.txt:line-containing-pattern`?

Comment: And you seem to want `<html`> followed by the remainder of the line. What about any text on the line _before_ the matching word?

Comment: @steeldriver I prefer comma. But can be anything I guess. Yes, if a match is found, I want the whole line.

Comment: @roaima It think your suggested format works too. But I can not get why not comma?

Comment: @roaima  The keyword I search about is not necessarily <html> it can be other words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `grep` command will do exactly what you have accepted in the comments. (If you can guarantee there is more than one file, then you can omit `-H`.)

```
grep -FH '<html>' *
```

The `-F` flag switches off Regular Expression processing, so the string is treated as a literal.

Comment: How to write the file name where the keyword is found? and the whole line? In an append way? I mean I want all the results in one file.

Comment: That's what it does. Just redirect the output to the target file.